# Ruby: String no longer mixes in Enumerable in 1.9

Tags: ruby, code-formatting

So how can I still be able to write beautiful code such as:

```
'im a string meing!'.pop
```

Note: `str.chop` isn't sufficient answer

Comment: because it from 'test' it returns 'tes'. unlike how .pop returns 't'

Comment: Doesn't work in 1.8.7 either -- not that I have any idea what it is supposed to do.  Which by itself is sort of a warning sign, I think: when Ruby code isn't immediately obvious, it's probably not optimal.

Comment: Note that in 1.8 string were enumerable *by line*. So even if string.pop had ever worked (which is not the case because Enumerable doesn't have pop or any other mutating method), it would have removed the last *line*, not word as you seem to expect.

Comment: If I ever needed an example of why giving programmers the power to shoot themselves in the foot is bad, I got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not what an enumerable string atually enumerates. Is a string a sequence of ...

- lines,
- characters,
- codepoints or
- bytes?

The answer is: all of those, any of those, either of those or neither of those, depending on the context. Therefore, you have to tell Ruby which of those you actually want.

There are several methods in the `String` class which return enumerators for any of the above. If you want the pre-1.9 behavior, your code sample would be

```
'im a string meing!'.bytes.to_a.pop
```

This looks kind of ugly, but there is a reason for it: a string is a sequence. You are treating it as a stack. A stack is not a sequence, in fact it pretty much is the *opposite* of a sequence.

Comment: Nice answer, but the string still has all of its original characters in memory.

Comment: well, you could always `def String.pop; self.bytes.to_a.pop; end` I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

That's not beautiful :)

Also #pop is not part of Enumerable, it's part of Array.

The reason why String is not enumerable is because there are no 'natural' units to enumerate, should it be on a character basis or a line basis? Because of this String does not have an #each

String instead provides the #each_char and #each_byte and #each_line methods for iteration in the way that you choose.

Comment: I know, I'm learning. But it's a lot better than str[str.lenght]

Comment: Use str[-1] to get the last character.

Comment: I know but I'm kind of anal retentive about this atm. Well actually that isn't too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't like str[str.length], how about

```
'im a string meing!'[-1]  # returns last character as a character value
```

or

```
'im a string meing!'[-1,1]  # returns last character as a string
```

or, if you need it modified in place as well, while keeping it an easy one-liner:

```
class String
  def pop
    last = self[-1,1]
    self.chop!
    last
  end
end
```

Comment: pop removes the element as well.  Not sure if that's one of his requirements.

Comment: True, it does remove the last element and that does make things more complex. These are still good alternatives to learn from for me though.

Comment: updated to remove the last character as well (in the String::pop definition)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

s = "I'm a string meing!"
s, last_char = s.rpartition(/./)
p [s, last_char]    # => ["I'm a string meing", "!"]
```

String.rpartition is new for 1.9 but it's been back-ported to 1.8.7.  It searches a string for a regular expression, starting at the end and working backwards.  It returns the part of the string before the match, the match, and the part of the string after the match (which we discard here).

Answer (score 1):

`String#slice!` and `String#insert` is going to get you much closer to what you want without converting your strings to arrays.

For example, to simulate `Array#pop` you can do:

```
text = '¡Exclamation!'
mark = text.slice! -1

mark == '!'          #=> true
text                 #=> "¡Exclamation"
```

Likewise, for `Array#shift`:

```
text = "¡Exclamation!"
inverted_mark = text.slice! 0

inverted_mark == '¡' #=> true
text                 #=> "Exclamation!"
```

Naturally, to do an `Array#push` you just use one of the concatenation methods:

```
text = 'Hello'
text << '!'          #=> "Hello!"
text.concat '!'      #=> "Hello!!"
```

To simulate `Array#unshift` you use `String#insert` instead, it's a lot like the inverse of slice really:

```
text = 'World!'
text.insert 0, 'Hello, ' #=> "Hello, World!"
```

You can also grab chunks from the middle of a string in multiple ways with slice.

First you can pass a start position and length:

```
text = 'Something!'
thing = text.slice 4, 5
```

And you can also pass a Range object to grab absolute positions:

```
text = 'This is only a test.'
only = text.slice (8..11)
```

In Ruby 1.9 using `String#slice` like this is identical to `String#[]`, but if you use the bang method `String#slice!` it will actually remove the substring you specify.

```
text = 'This is only a test.'
only = text.slice! (8..12)
text == 'This is a test.'      #=> true
```

Here's a slightly more complex example where we reimplement a simple version of `String#gsub!` to do a search and replace:

```
text = 'This is only a test.'
search = 'only'
replace = 'not'

index = text =~ /#{search}/
text.slice! index, search.length
text.insert index, replace

text == 'This is not a test.'  #=> true
```

Of course 99.999% of the time, you're going to want to use the aforementioned `String.gsub!` which will do the exact same thing:

```
text = 'This is only a test.'
text.gsub! 'only', 'not' 

text == 'This is not a test.'  #=> true
```

references:

- [Ruby String Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String)